# save django model queryset into another model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have two Django models

```
class Invoice(models.Model):
      id              = models.IntegerField()
      is_converted    = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

this model keeps the information about invoices and quotations

and another model containing items details of particular invoice/quotation

```
class Items(models.Model):
      document        = models.Foreignkey(Invoice, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      price           = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
      name            = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

now I want to convert the quotation record from model `Invoice` to Sales Invoice

I have copied the data from the `Invoice` model row into another row (as I want to keep the Quotation record also)

My problem is copying items from the `Item` model of quotation record into a newly generated invoice record.

I've tried this

```
quotation_items = Items.objects.filter(document=id)
```

this returns normal queryset

```
<QuerySet [<items: items object (238)>, <items: items object (240)>, <items: items object (241)>]>
```

Now I want to save these records into the `Items` model for the converted invoices.

Is there any way of saving querysets into Django models?

Comment: For mass creation you can use ```bulk_create```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue with `bulk_create` thanks to @Marat 's comment

```
quotation_items = Items.objects.filter(document=id)

new_item_list = []

    for item_obj in quotation_items:
        item_obj.pk = None                 
        item_obj.document = new_obj          # newly created invoice intance
        new_item_list.append(item_obj)

    tbl_invoice_description.objects.bulk_create(new_item_list)
```

I want to copy querysets into new rows with pk and document columns changed